# Parallelize search operations on mulitple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple huge data frames which I am trying to map using unique identifiers from one data frame as a search basis for the others. I want to speed up the process, as the whole thing takes over 6 hours to complete. What I am currently doing is using the `df[df['Column'] == 'Unique value']` method to search for the key in the other data frames, stringing the matches together and appending to a new data frame. This process takes around 0.2 seconds per entry which I feel is a bit on the higher side. I have tried `apply.async()` as a means to parallelize, but the process created for every unique key iteration takes more time than running it on a single core. What can I do differently to speed this up?

A relevant snippet of my current implementation is as follows:

```
def indexer(df, index):
   return df[df['Column'] == 'index']

def mapping:
   with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
      for i in df1.iloc[:,:]['Column'].unqiue():
         p1 = pool.apply_async(indexer, (df1,index,))
         p2 = pool.apply_async(indexer, (df2,index,))
         p3 = pool.apply_async(indexer, (df3,index,))
         
         df1 = p1.get()
         df2 = p2.get()
         df3 = p3.get()
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Do you know about [dask dataframes](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) it's an API that works well with pandas and allows for multiple processes. You might also gain some performance by [using eval and query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html)

Comment: I tried Dask, but it did not lead to a significant reduction in compute time. As well for eval and query I am unsure of how to use them to search for specific strings in the dataframe.